# What instrument is this?

Tags: instruments, brass, tuba, sousaphone

[image: unkown instrument]

I thought it was a tuba, and it sounds like one, but looking around for pictures it seems the tuba is a smaller instrument. Is this an unusual type of tuba, or what?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like a [Sousaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sousaphone) to me.  :)

Comment: i.e. Marching Tuba--and this one is made out of fiberglass instead of brass.

Comment: This. A sousaphone is, for all intents and purposes, a BBb tuba, just arranged differently so you can sling it over the shoulder and march around with it. There is sometimes a difference in the rate of growth of the tubing and certainly a difference in the bell, which can affect the timbre of the instrument, but as the example from the picture is made of fiberglass I would think that would have an even greater effect.

Answer (score 7):

That is a Sousaphone, but this one is made mostly of fiberglass plastic (except for the small brass pipes and valves.) Other Sousaphones are made with brass parts (sometimes silver plated.) It is not "Home-Made" - Sousaphones are manufactured by several music instrument companies in the US, Europe and Asia. 
Sousaphones are usually pitched in BBb (old ones were also available in EEb) but Tubas are made in BBb, CC, EEb and F. (Euphoniums are usually Bb - just slightly smaller than the F Tuba, and Tenor Horns are Eb.)

Answer (score 2):

i think the man in the photo is a member of "Los luthiers" (a group from argentina). if he indeed is, i bet he built his instrument quite probably based on a tuba. It is not uncommon for them to build their own instruments, with cans, bottles, etc.

Comment: He indeed is from Les Luthiers, I forgot to mention in the question.

Comment: yup a sousaphone indeed as cornbead ninja says

Comment: My friend has a Souza exactly like that. I doubt the instrument in the picture is hand made.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a Tuba/Sousaphone.  The smaller Tuba you're referring to is probably a Tenor Tuba/Euphonium.

Comment: More information about the Sousaphone- http://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sousaphone